# Bookdown: Cross-reference figure in another file

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, cross-reference, literate-programming

I have taken the plunge and am preparing a manuscript for publication entirely in RStudio using bookdown. In the main text I would like to cross-reference figures in a separate supporting information .Rmd file.

Let's say this is my main text file called `main.Rmd`:

```
---
title: "Main text"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    toc: no
---
Here is the main text file. I would like to refer to \@ref(fig:supporting-figure).
```

Here is the supporting text called `supporting.Rmd`, and the figure to refer to, saved in the same folder:

````
---
title: "Supporting info"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    toc: no
---

Here is the supporting text.

```{r supporting-figure}
plot(cars)
```
````

How can I cross-ref `supporting-figure` in the main text?

I have checked the section on cross-references in Yihui's [bookdown manual](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/cross-references.html), but I cannot see how to extend this to cross-references between files.

I also found this question:
[Cross-reference figure in a separate Rmarkdown (PDF) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51345405/cross-reference-figure-in-a-separate-rmarkdown-pdf-file/51357211#comment89810076_51357211)
 but the accepted answer does not work for me (perhaps because I am using bookdown rather than base Rmarkdown?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and came up with this solution if you aim at compiling 2 different pdfs. It relies on LaTeX's xr package for cross references: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52532269/576684

Answer (score 6):

I am not entirely sure how you are compiling these two files into a single bookdown document, because as it stands they are just two separate R Markdown documents. But there are two issues:

1. **Figures need a caption to be cross-referenced**

You can only cross-reference figures which have a caption assigned with `fig.cap`, as [explained here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/figures.html):

> If we assign a figure caption to a code chunk via the chunk option
>   fig.cap, R plots will be put into figure environments, which will be
>   automatically labeled and numbered, and can also be cross-referenced.

2. **Incorrectly configured bookdown project**:

From what I can tell, you have not got the project configured correctly for `bookdown`:

- The main file should be called `index.Rmd`
- Supporting files should not have any YAML
- You should include `site: bookdown::bookdown_site` in the YAML of the main documene

> Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51521542/7347699) for some tips on a minimal bookdown file.

---

**Solution**

**index.Rmd**

```
---
title: "Main text"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    toc: no
---
Here is the main text file. I would like to refer to \@ref(fig:supporting-figure).
```

**supporting.Rmd**

````
Here is the supporting text.

```{r supporting-figure, fig.cap= "Some Figure"}
plot(cars)
```
````

[image]

Comment: `site: bookdown::bookdown_site` was spot on ! Finally see why not to leave it out.

Comment: Would this work for officedown as well?